# how to make colors generated via Javascript be stored permanently in CSS file with or without use of PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a js color picker. Now the user picks some colors one by one using it and these are applied to the page using JQuery.

After this the color is applied to the present page using JQuery.

My question is this- how can I store this color permanently into the CSS file with or without PHP code?

Comment: Storing it on the server DEFINITELY requires server-side language, so you have to use PHP in this case, but update the CSS file can be a bit difficult, you will need to read the CSS file and parse then then figure where the change will be then replace current value then save the new CSS file, it is unclear to me what you're trying to do but if you are trying to make your website theme customize-able by users then you can't store it into CSS this will effect everyone loading the page, I would suggest storing properties you want the user to change in the database

Comment: You might want to consider storing the values client-side instead by using Local Storage http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html http://jsfiddle.net/Benjol/HMEVd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you'd have to save the variable to your server and would need to write your style-sheet in a language that would be able to pull variables from your Server (eg. PHP).
Something along these lines:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
    $colour = you_custom_function('colour');
?>
    background-colour: <?= $colour ?>;
```

For the actual fetch process in PHP I'd use mysqli : http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php